# React State changing to false automatically without setting it

Tags: reactjs

I have this situation where I need to set the sortAscending order to Boolean true or false based on its selection. Once I try to sort it changes the state to true and immediately changes back to false. This is affecting me in Lazy loading of the list.

```
handleSortRoomsOnClick: function(sortBy) {
    if(sortBy == this.state.sortBy) {
        this.setState({
            isSortAsc: !this.state.isSortAsc,
            page: 1
        });
        this.handleFetchRooms(1, sortBy, this.state.isSortAsc);
    } else {
        this.setState({
            sortBy: sortBy,
            isSortAsc: true,
            page: 1
        });
        this.handleFetchRooms(1, sortBy, true);
    }
},
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but use a callback in `setState` to use previous state and ensure your state is set correctly: `this.setState(prevState => ({ isSortAsc: !prevState.isSortAsc, page: 1 }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `setState` is asynchronous. You can't set it and then immediately reference the value `this.state.isSortAsync`. So, you can save it in a variable like below, or use a callback in `setState`.

```
handleSortRoomsOnClick: function(sortBy) {
    if(sortBy == this.state.sortBy) {
        const isSortAsc = !this.state.isSortAsc;
        this.setState({
            isSortAsc: isSortAsc,
            page: 1
        });
        this.handleFetchRooms(1, sortBy, isSortAsc);
    } else {
        this.setState({
            sortBy: sortBy,
            isSortAsc: true,
            page: 1
        });
        this.handleFetchRooms(1, sortBy, true);
    }
}
```

Edit: thought I might condense this a bit:

```
handleSortRoomsOnClick(sortBy) {
    const isSortAsc = (sortBy === this.state.sortBy) ? !this.state.isSortAsc: true;
    this.setState({
        sortBy,
        isSortAsc,
        page: 1
    });
    this.handleFetchRooms(1, sortBy, isSortAsc);
}
```